# Having difficulties displaying all content on my wishlist table

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to retrieve the data on my wishlist table, for a particular user, so far it only retrieves the first data on the table, just returning one array instead of the three in the table with same user id

```
 public function getWishlistByUserId($id){
    $wishlists = Wishlist::where('userId', $id)->get();
    foreach($wishlists as $wishlist){
        $products = Product::where('id', $wishlist->productId)->get();
        return $products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bunch of issues here... You're looping, but the return statement in the loop won't do anything. Using `->get()` on a query for a single ID is redundant, as it will return a `Collection` of a single `Product`; can use `->first()` to just fetch the product, it's inefficient due to calling additional queries in a loop (i.e. if this user had 1000 wishlists, it would call 1000 database queries), etc etc. Consider refactoring, use relationships, look into pushing data to an array properly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because the `foreach` loop returns a value during the first iteration. Place your `return` statement outside the loop. Also you could improve your performence by making use of [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

An example could be:

```
// Product.php
public function wishlists()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class);
}

// Your method
public function getWishlistByUserId($id)
{
    return Product::whereHas('wishlists', function ($query) use ($id) {
        $query->where('userId', $id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Possibly `belongsTo` instead of `hasMany` but we can't know for sure without DB schema.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally this is n+1 situation

So i will suggest to use laravel relationship like:

**in your whishlist model**

```
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'productId','id');
}
```

**get data with relationship**

```
 public function getWishlistByUserId($id){
    $wishlists = Wishlist::with('product')->where('userId', $id)->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it working this way, i just pushed the result into an array, and then returned it outside the loop, thanks everyone for your help

```
public function getWishlistByUserId($id){


    $wishlists = Wishlist::where('userId', $id)->get();

    $wishlist = [];
    foreach($wishlists as $wish){
    $product = Product::where('id', $wish->productId)->get();
    array_push($wishlist, $product);
    }
    return $wishlist;

}
```